# SQL Join to either table, Best way or alternative design

Tags: sql, database-design

I am designing a database for a system and I came up with the following three tables
[image]

My problem is that an `Address` can belong to either a `Person` or a `Company` (or other things in the future) So how do I model this?

- I discarded putting the address information in both tables (Person
  and Company) because of it would be repeated
- I thought of adding two columns (`PersonId` and `CompanyId`) to the
  `Address` table and keep one of them null, but then I will need to add
  one column for every future relation like this that appears (for
  example an asset can have an address where its located at)
- The last option that occur to me was to create two columns, one
  called `Type` and other `Id`, so a pair of values would represent a
  single record in the target table, for example: `Type=Person,Id=5` and
  `Type=Company,Id=9` this way I can Join the right table using the type
  and it will only be two columns no matter how many tables relate to
  this table. But I cannot have constraints which reduce data integrity

I don't know if I am designing this properly. I think this should be a common issue (I've faced it at least three times during this small design in objects like Contact information, etc...) But I could not find many information or examples that would resemble mine.

Thanks for any guidance that you can give me

Comment: Can a company or person have more than one address in your example?

Comment: Yes, a person can have a home address and a work address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several basic approaches you could take, depending on how much you want to future proof your system.

In general, Has-One relationships are modeled by a foreign key on the owning entity, pointing to the primary key on the owned entity. So you would have an `AddressId` on both `Company` and `Person`,which would be a foreign key to `Address.Id`. The complexity in your case is how to handle the fact that a person can have multiple addresses. If you are 100% sure that there will only ever be a home and work address, you could put two foreign key columns on `Person`, but this becomes a big problem if there's a third, fourth, fifth etc. address. The other option is to create a join table, `PersonAddress`, with three columns a `PersonId` an `AddressId` and a `AddressType`, to indicate whether its a home work or whatever address.

Comment: Thumbs up for the join table PersonAddress. But also remember that a company can have multiple addresses (physical address, mailing address, cargo delivery address) and could have multiple sites as well - so you should do the same for CompanyAddress.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. So in case that there is another entity that has addresses, then I would create a new crossing table for each right?

Comment: That would probably be the best approach